# linked list in c programming language

Tags: c, linked-list

i am trying a sample linked list program. what is the problem with the following code? When i try to access the values...segmentation fault arises. i can't access the values beyond the root.What is wrong in the following?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};

void create(int n,struct node** ref){
    struct node *temp,*newnode;
    newnode=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->val=n;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(*ref==NULL){
        *ref=newnode;
        temp=newnode;
    }
    else{
        temp->next=newnode; 
        temp=newnode;
    }
    return;
}  

int main(){
    struct node *root=NULL,*p;
    int n,i,j=1;
    while(j==1){
        printf("enter the value...\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        create(n,&root);
        //printf("%d",root->val);
        printf("Press 1 to continue..\n");
        scanf("%d",&j);
    }
    p=root;
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d-",p->val);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the line `temp->next=newnode` you access `temp` without initializing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link list creation method is not correct. you did not assign memory to temp and try to assign newnode to temp->next.
correct is below:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
};

node *lastnode = NULL;

void create(int n,struct node** ref){
    struct node *temp,*newnode;
    newnode=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->val=n;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(*ref==NULL){
        *ref=newnode;
      //  temp=newnode;
    }
    else{
      //  temp->next=newnode; 
      //  temp=newnode;
        lastnode->next = newnode;
    }
    lastnode = newnode;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I am not writing a production ready code. Intension is to highlight the problem in asked code. Further optimization can be done upto ‘n’ level. No global, no static, no unused local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to declare temp as static. At least that works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

struct node{
  int val;
  struct node* next;
};

void create(int n,struct node** ref){
  static struct node *temp;
  struct node *newnode;

  newnode=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
  newnode->val=n;
  newnode->next=NULL;
  if(*ref==NULL){
    *ref=newnode;
    temp=newnode;
  }
  else{
    temp->next=newnode; 
    temp=newnode;
  }

  return;
}
```

The output:

```
enter the value...
1
Press 1 to continue..
1
enter the value...
2
Press 1 to continue..
1
enter the value...
3
Press 1 to continue..
0
1-2-3-
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated memory to temp.Add the below second line.

```
 newnode=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
 temp=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: She doesn't want to allocate memory for `temp`. She doesn't need `temp` at all.

Comment: Yes , you are right but the seg fault is happening when the temp is being assinged some value. Logically I agree with temp is not needed. Seems she is a beginner... and I too in the beginning faced these kind of problems in C :)

Comment: Yes, but the it's not a good advice to solve a segfault in already mem-leaking code with new memory leaks…

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

The segfault happens when you try to access `temp` which isn't initilized. And you don't need that variable anyway and the two lines with

```
temp=newnode;
```

don't do anything; change

```
temp->next=newnode;
```

to

```
(*ref)->next=newnode;
```

and delete `temp` entirely.

The second problem is a memory leak caused by

```
       create(n,&root);
```

with the same root value each time (your list currently never gets more than two elements).

```
int main(){
    struct node *root=NULL;
    struct node **current = &root;
    int n,i,j=1;
    while(j==1){
        printf("enter the value...\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        /*create(n,&root);*/
        create(n, current);
        current = &(*current)->next;
        //printf("%d",root->val);
        printf("Press 1 to continue..\n");
        scanf("%d",&j);
    }
    struct node *p;
    p=root;
    while(p!=NULL){
        printf("%d-",p->val);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```